# Add an overall order with case order

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql with a where statement and then an ordering statment.

My ordering statement is like this

```
'ORDER BY CASE 
WHEN '.$col.' LIKE \''.$searchTerm.'\' THEN '.$c_0++.' 
WHEN '.$col.' LIKE \''.$searchTerm.'%\' THEN '.$c_20++.' 
WHEN '.$col.'LIKE \'%'.$searchTerm.'%\' THEN '.$c_40++.'
ELSE '.$c_60.' END,'.$col;
```

This gets done a couple of times depending on how many columns and then also splitting my search term up. This works pretty well but when there are couple of results matching the first order statement they display then on ID order, which is not what I want.

How do I add `ORDER BY 'RELEASE_DATE' DESC` to this.

I have tried adding it my sql in numorous places but just get sql santex errors coming back to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add another clause to the `order by`:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN '.$col.' LIKE \''.$searchTerm.'\' THEN '.$c_0++.' 
               WHEN '.$col.' LIKE \''.$searchTerm.'%\' THEN '.$c_20++.' 
               WHEN '.$col.'LIKE \'%'.$searchTerm.'%\' THEN '.$c_40++;
               ELSE '.$c_60.'
          END),
         (CASE WHEN '.$col.' LIKE \''.$searchTerm.'\' THEN RELEASE_DATE END) desc,
         '.$col
```

Comment: Worked perfect. Thanks so much